# Problems using SDL_mixer to play .ogg files

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2, sdl-mixer

I'm trying to use SDL mixer to play .ogg files in my game. It appears to be installed correctly, it outputs this during the process:

```
checking vorbis/vorbisfile.h usability... yes
checking vorbis/vorbisfile.h presence... yes
checking for vorbis/vorbisfile.h... yes
checking for ov_open_callbacks in -lvorbisfile... yes
-- dynamic libvorbisfile -> libvorbisfile.dylib
```

Which, if I am not mistaken, appears to suggest that .ogg files should work and the libraries are linked correctly.

When I play the game however the .ogg music file does not play. It gives the following output to the terminal:

```
Could not load music: Error -
```

This output is generated from the following line of code:

```
std::cout << "Could not load music: ERROR - " << Mix_GetError() << std::endl;
```

Interestingly, it appears that Mix_GetError() is producing no output, even though there is an error.

Furthermore, if i try try a .wav song file instead it does work so the problem seems specific to .ogg files.

I assume the problem is something to do with how I am linking libraries, I've tried a few things though and I cant seem to fix it. Does anyone have any suggestions on what may be the cause of my problems/ how I could fix them?

Comment: How do you  know there was an error (which function returned which value)?

Comment: Sorry, i think I was maybe a little ambiguous in my original post. When I say "even though there is an error" its not that a specific error message is appearing, its just that the .ogg file is not playing whereas the .wav does. I am just assuming there is an error.
Edit: if its helpful I can show the functions and how i call them

Comment: You would know there was an error if a function returned an error code. If there wasn't an error then that is why Mix_GetError returns no error message.